# There are two integers whose sum and difference are perfect squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic

*Definition*: A positive integer $m$ is said to be a perfect square if there exists an integer $n$ such that $m = n^2$.

> Write a detailed structured proof to prove that there exist two distinct positive integers whose sum and difference are both perfect squares.

How would I write this in logical notation?

Comment: Are you asking about how to write the statement in logical notation, or how to write the proof in logical notation?  Do you have an idea for an informal proof?

Comment: Proof : 5+4 = 9.  5-4 = 1.

Comment: Euler is alive, but is working on rather mundane problems these days :-)

Comment: @TrevorWilson Yes 16 and 20 the sum and difference of these integers are perfect squares but I dont know how to put it in logical notation so I can begin to prove it,

Comment: Well, what language are you working in?  You may have to express 16 as $SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS(0)$, for example.

Comment: @user104350 Much more interesting : Do there exist infinitely many pairs of distinct positive integers whose sum and difference are both perfect square?  What do you think?

Comment: No this is existential quantification. I am not working in any language beginner logical notation.

Comment: i was thinking, there exists a in N, there exists b in N, a+b=m and  a-b=n

Comment: Oh, so you are just asking how to express the _statement_ in logical notation, rather than expressing the proof in logical notation?  You are on the right track but you have to say that the two numbers are distinct and you have to mention that their sums and differences are both perfect squares.

Comment: @TrevorWilson Yes, proving it isn't hard but I am having difficulty actually expressing it in logical notation. I was also thinking, there exists m in N, there exists a in N, there exists b in N, if m = n^2 then m = a+b and m =a-b

Comment: What is the "it"?  The statement, or its proof?

Comment: Your latest attempt at formalizing the statement is not right.  Problems: (1) you still don't say that $a$ and $b$ are distinct, (2) you have put $m=n^2$ in the hypothesis, rather than in the conclusion, (3) the $n$ isn't bound with a quantifier, and (4) the conclusion implies that $a+b = a-b$, which is not what you want to say because $a+b$ and $a-b$ will be _different_ perfect squares.

Comment: @TrevorWilson 'It' being the statement. Ok, by saying there exisits some a and there exists some b doesn't this show that they are distinct by using existential quantification

Comment: Nope, so for example the statement "$\exists a\,\exists b\,(a=b)$" is true.

Comment: @TrevorWilson oh ok so I would just add AND a DNE b

Comment: Yes, that would fix problem (1).

Comment: @TrevorWilson could I put m = a -b and n = a+b

Comment: Yes, although then $m = n^2$ is not something you want to say.

Answer (score 2):

We want to prove :

> $$\exists a \in \Bbb Z_+\; \exists b \in \Bbb Z_+\; \exists m \in \Bbb Z_+\;\exists n \in \Bbb Z_+\; \bigl((a-b=m^2) \land (a+b=n^2)\bigr).$$

Since all the quantifiers are existential, one adequate proof is to find $a,b,m,n$ that satisfy the desired equations.  If you start with $m,n$ of the same parity, with $m \lt n$ that is not hard.

Answer (score 2):

$(a,b)=(2n^2+2n+1,2n^2+2n)$ works.

Answer (score -1):

hey I'm in the same class as you, and stuck on this as well.  This is what I have so far.
I'm going off the direct proof structure of the existential (chapter 3.7)

This is my general structure:

Let $a = 40$ and $b = 24$.

Then $a \in \Bbb Z_+$ and $b \in \Bbb Z_+$.

Then $$a+b=40+24=64=8^2 \tag a\label a$$
and
$$a-b=40-24=16=4^2 \tag b\label b,$$
so $$a \in \Bbb Z_+,\quad b \in \Bbb Z_+,\quad a+b=x^2,\quad a-b=y^2 \tag c\label c$$

I'm not really sure how to format it properly.  Also I'm not sure if line \eqref{a} and line \eqref{b} can/are supposed to be combined like what I did on line \eqref{c}.  I'm not even sure if line \eqref{c} is correct format wise...

Comment: We have to write the original statement in logical notation aswell right?

Comment: hey, not entirely sure :(. you have contact info so we can communicate more easily?  full disclosure I'm a bit behind in this course so I'm planning on doing this as I get caught up.  I'm looking at the past year solutions to see what they mean by detailed structured proof since I don't know if they want it commented as well     ***when they say detailed proof structure they mean just the formal way we've been doing it***